# sendmail - local mail delivery if user exists, otherwise to external mail server?

Tags: linux, debian, email, sendmail, mx-record

i have a debian vps with webmin,

The TLD for the server has its MX pointing to a different server,

I would like it so any mail generated locally, say by the shopping cart would be relayed/forwarded onto the third party mail server,

While a few chosen address's say those with user accounts/mail boxes like root and postmaster would have their mail delivered locally.

Is this possible, how ?

thanks,
Hayden.

Comment: You want SOME email addresses in the TLD to be delivered locally, do not you? Is the TLD on the list of local email doamins? `echo '$=w' | sendmail -bt`

Answer (score 0):

For local delivery add an alias in `/etc/aliases` to the user-id prefixed with `real-`, for example:

```
john:   real-john
```

`root` should already be aliased to a local user-id.  Configure it as above or alias it to a different user.

For delivery to a relay server configure your mail server to use a smarthost, and specify the desired server as the smarthost.

Typically, Debian will use `exim4` or `postfix` rather than `sendmail`.  `exim4` should already be configured for the above to work.   I believe postfix is also configured similarly.  The `real-` prefix is used internally to deliver some failure notices, and is available for other uses, such as yours.